# is not identical to 'int'

Tags: xcode, swift

Добрый день! Разбираюсь в Swift, по официальной книге Apple.
В главе про функции наткнулся на пример, который не работает:

```
func alignRight(var string: String, count: Int, pad: Character) -> String {
    let amountToPad = count - count(string)
    if amountToPad < 1 {
        return string
    }
    let padString = String(pad)
    for _ in 1...amountToPad {
        string = padString + string
    }
    return string
}
let originalString = "hello"
let paddedString = alignRight(originalString, 10, "-")
```

Если вставить этот код в playground выдает ошибку: 
[image: ошибка]

Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка исчезает при такой записи:

```
let amountToPad = count - Swift.count(string)
```

(из комментария pavelip)
Так же помогает переименовать переменную count во что-то другое, например, _count:

```
func alignRight(var string: String, _сount: Int, pad: Character) -> String {
let amountToPad = _сount - count(string)
```

Очевидно, это происходило из-за конфликта названия переменной с названием функции.

Comment: в новом это должно быть что-то типа string.characters.count

Answer (score 0):

```
func alignRight(var string: String, totalLength: Int, pad: Character) -> String {
    let amountToPad = totalLength - string.characters.count
    if amountToPad < 1 {
        return string
    }
    let padString = String(pad)
    for _ in 1...amountToPad {
        string = padString + string
    }
    return string
}
let originalString = "hello"
let paddedString = alignRight(originalString, totalLength: 10, pad: "-")
```

Comment: теперь другая ошибка) "String does not have a member named 'characters'

Comment: Какая ц вас версия swift и xcode?

Comment: xcode 6.4, соответственно swift 1.2

Comment: Swift 2: string.characters

Comment: Попробуйте переиметонать параметр count в cnt и вызывать так: let amountToPad = cnt - count(string)